# ValueEventListeners are never called

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a specific value from my Firebase database as follows:

```
databaseReference.child("update/version").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final Long version = (Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        if (version != null) firebaseVersion = version.intValue();

        needsUpdate = storedVersion != firebaseVersion;

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

The code inside of the listener is never called. I ran it in debug mode with a breakpoint on the first line and nothing happens. Previously this hasn't been an issue, but now none of my uses of valueEventListener work. I tried switching to `.addValueEventListener` and changing it on the database but still get the same results.

Why aren't my listeners being called?

Answer (score 0):

Does the onCancelled callback get called? If yes, log the DatabaseError.

Also, is the user logged in via FirebaseAuth? This is a requirement to read from the database.

Comment: onCancelled never gets triggered, either. The listeners are only added if the user is signed in, otherwise it passes over the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between those two methods. You cannot change one method with another and expect the same behaviour.

> 1. `addValueEventListener()` keep listening to a query or a database reference it is attached.
> 2. `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` executes `onDataChange()` method immediately and after executing that method once it stops listening to the reference location it is attached to.

But remember, `onDataChange()` method is called with a snapshot of the data at a particular location each time that data changes. If there are no changes, `onDataChange()` method is not triggered.

Comment: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` will get the current state of the data, regardless of it there are any active changes. The reason why I specified that I also tried `addValueEventListener()` is because I wanted it to be clear that I had a long-term listener on the item and was actively making changes to try to trigger it.

Comment: If you are using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`, it's not triggered not even once?

Comment: Have you set the correct read/write rules in your Firebase Console?

Comment: Default rules, both accessible to any signed in user.